# How to edit a .NET config file with WiX AFTER its installation

Tags: wix, installation, app-config

I need to change an entry of a .NET config file.
The problem is that the App.config in the project folder needs to stay untouched, because otherwise the application won't work within the IDE anymore.

I need the **installed** .NET config file changed **after** its installation.

Whenever I try to reference that file and build my installer, i get an error that the file can't be found. Of course it can't be found there, because the installation folder doesn't exist, when I build the installer.

How can I achieve that goal?

Answer (score 1):

You are not saying how you are editing it, but WIX has two facilities for doing this properly. You can use [XmlFile](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/xmlfile.html) or [XmlConfig](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/xmlconfig.html). These are scheduled at the proper time by WIX for you. You can set the path to the file a few ways as they accept a formatted string, so you can use an expected installed path or the file id.